# Где располагать index.html и другие html-файлы: корневая директория или папка dist/build?

Tags: html, вёрстка, структуры

Всем привет. В нескольких обучающих видео на YouTube видел, что в процессе верстки сайтов файл index.html располагают то в корневой директории, то в папке build/dist (та, что для продакшена).

Тот же GitHub Pages вроде привык находить index.html в корневой директории. Да и на хостингах вроде так же (поправьте, если ошибаюсь). Если его располагать в папке dist/build, то "найдут" ли его?

В чём же всё-таки принципиальная разница или, возможно, стандарт?

Answer (score 1):

`dist/build` - это то, что должно пойти на сервер. То есть на сервере это корень проекта, если иное не задано вами. И там index.html окажется в корне. Вы можете настроить например что на сервере тоже будет `dist/build`, но тогда нужно будет настроить маршрутизацию на эту папку вместо корня проекта.

В корневой директории можно располагать, если у вас нет билдинга проекта (исходник который вы пишете = результат). А в `dist/build` руками помещать ничего нельзя. Туда билдер помещает результат своей работы. А на следующем этапе, деплое, всё из этой папки идёт в корень проекта на сервере, или в указанную вами папку.